# CSS: position absolute - how to set "left" property so it refers to the middle of the positioned element?

Tags: css

I drew a circle with svg (which is also positioned absolute) and I would like to put text into the middle of the circle. It's is no problem if the text is 1 character long, but the content of the page may change dynamically and the text width could be 2 or 3 characters long as well:

```
<div id="someDivWrap" style="position:relative">
    <svg id="someCircle" style="position:absolute;left:200px;right:300px">
        ...
    </svg>
    <span id="textInMidOfCirc" style="position:absolute;left:245px;right:341px">X</span>
</div>
```

But text in the middle of the circle could be `X` or `XX` or `XXX`.

EDIT:

here is the complete code:

```
<div id="someDivWrap" style="position:relative;width:174px;height:434px;border: 4px solid #525878;background-image: linear-gradient(#5bb8ff, #5f80e4); margin-left:255px">

    <svg id="someCircle" style="position:absolute;left:-120px;top:300px" width="120" height="240">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="CalenderGradient" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f8e498" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#d2811d" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#CalenderGradient)" />
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="15" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="black" />
    </svg>
    <span id="textInMidOfCirc" style="position:absolute; left:-75px; top:341px; color:lime; font-weight:bold">X</span>

</div>
```

Yes, and I need the circle as an SVG.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Is the svg a fixed size?

Comment: yes, svg is fixed size

Comment: If you made the circle with plain html and css, it would be much easier. Is there a need to use svg?

Comment: @Dejan.S if `X` is in the middle then `XX` and `XXX` will be shifted to the right, and I want to have any text in the middle

Comment: There is nothing in the code given so far which would enable centering text. Please make a runnable snippet which includes the whole SVG and any other CSS of relevance. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Why don't you just make the span as wide as the SVG itself - and then use `text-align: center`?

Answer (score 1):

If I get this right you want this.

There are more ways to do this but you can add width and height to the container and a display flex to position (center) the text. Position the SVG absolute and keep the text relative.

Keep in mind I added a background-colour and border radius to the container that you can remove, it's only there for demo purposes.

```html
<div id="someDivWrap" style="position:relative; width: 300px; height: 300px; display: flex;
align-items: center; justify-content: center; background-color: aqua; border-radius: 50%;">
  <svg id="someCircle" style="position:absolute; top: 0;
    left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    ...
  </svg>

  <span id="textInMidOfCirc">X</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats, the point of the svg, if you did the circle with html and css? Can't we get rid of that?

Comment: @DanZuzevich Sure. Maybe the OP has something more planed for the SVG or maybe want to do icons/other shapes ect? I don't know but that's up to the OP to decide what and why :)